# How to programmatically check for duplicate row before insertion into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am a database newbie and am learning on python3.7 and mysql using end of day stock data. I've managed to programmatically load data into the database. However, I want to avoid inserting duplicate rows. I am parsing a text file line by line.

Here is my code so far.

```
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
import sys

ticker_file = 'C:/testfile.txt'

# Read the text file and add , to the end of the line.
def fun_read_file(ticker_file):
    host = 'localhost'
    user = 'user'
    password = 'password'
    db = 'trading'
    with open(ticker_file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            # Do something with 'line'
            stripped = line.strip('\n\r')
            value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7 = stripped.split(',')
            print(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7)
            # Call the csv_to_mysql function
            csv_to_mysql(host, user, password, db, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7)

def csv_to_mysql(host, user, password, db, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7):
    '''
    This function load a csv file to MySQL table according to
    the load_sql statement.
    '''
    load_sql = 'INSERT INTO asx (Symbol,Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
    args = [value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7]
    print('You are in csv_to_mysql')
    print(args)
    try:
        con = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                                user=user,
                                password=password,
                                db=db,
                                autocommit=True,
                                local_infile=1)
        print('Connected to DB: {}'.format(host))
        # Create cursor and execute Load SQL
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(load_sql, args)
        print('Successfully loaded the table from csv.')
        con.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: {}'.format(str(e)))
        sys.exit(1)

# Execution the script
fun_read_file(ticker_file)
```

And here is the current data in the table called asx:

```
mysql> select * from asx;

+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| Symbol | Date       | Open   | High   | Low    | Close  | Volume  |
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| 14D    | 2019-01-11 | 0.2950 | 0.2950 | 0.2750 | 0.2750 |  243779 |
| 14D    | 2019-01-11 | 0.2950 | 0.2950 | 0.2750 | 0.2750 |  243779 |
| 14D    | 2019-01-11 | 0.2950 | 0.2950 | 0.2750 | 0.2750 |  243779 |
| 14DO   | 2019-01-11 | 0.0700 | 0.0700 | 0.0700 | 0.0700 |       0 |
| 1AD    | 2019-01-11 | 0.2400 | 0.2400 | 0.2400 | 0.2400 |       0 |
| 1AG    | 2019-01-11 | 0.0310 | 0.0320 | 0.0310 | 0.0310 |  719145 |
| 1AL    | 2019-01-11 | 0.9100 | 0.9100 | 0.9100 | 0.9100 |       0 |
| 1ST    | 2019-01-11 | 0.0280 | 0.0280 | 0.0280 | 0.0280 |       0 |
| 3DP    | 2019-01-11 | 0.0500 | 0.0560 | 0.0500 | 0.0520 | 3919592 |
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
9 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

As you can see, the first three rows of data are all duplicates.
I have a ton of these files to import, and chances of duplicate rows are high.
Is there a way to check that the row I will be inserting doesn't already exist in the table?
Checking the Symbol and Date values should be enough to ensure uniqueness for this dataset. But I am unsure of how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Added for clarification:
Thanks very much for your input so far.

I've read the primary key responses and have follow up questions regarding them.
My understanding is that primary keys need to be unique inside a table. Due to the nature of End of Day Stock Data I may end up with the following rows.

```
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| Symbol | Date       | Open   | High   | Low    | Close  | Volume  |
+--------+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| 14D    | 2019-01-12 | 0.3000 | 0.4950 | 0.2950 | 0.4900 |  123456 |
| 14D    | 2019-01-11 | 0.2950 | 0.2950 | 0.2750 | 0.2750 |  243779 |
| 14D    | 2019-01-11 | 0.2950 | 0.2950 | 0.2750 | 0.2750 |  243779 |
| 14DO   | 2019-01-11 | 0.0700 | 0.0700 | 0.0700 | 0.0700 |       0 |
| 1AD    | 2019-01-11 | 0.2400 | 0.2400 | 0.2400 | 0.2400 |       0 |
```

As you can see Symbol 14D will have a row for each date. The data in row 1 is valid. However, rows 2 and 3 are duplicates. I would need to remove either row 2 or 3 in order to keep the table accurate.

In this scenario, should I still make Symbol and Date Primary Keys?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read **INSERT IGNORE**, **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** keywords for MySQL and also look into **PRIMARY KEY** and **UNIQUE** constraints.

Here is a quick link that can solve your problem:
[Mysql Handling Duplicates](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm)

If you still have questions, I can answer them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have posted follow up questions above with regards to your proposed answer. Could you please review and let me know. Ta.

Answer (score 1):

I am still a beginner in Python, but I know databases. What I would do is first do a SELECT query to verify if a record with the given Symbol and Date exists in the MySQL table, and only perform the INSERT if the SELECT returned 0 rows. You should also consider making these two columns your primary key for that table. That will ensure that no duplicates are inserted (but inserting a duplicate might raise an exception which must be handled).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have posted follow up questions above with regards to your proposed answer. Could you please review and let me know. Ta.

Comment: The select would be redundant

Comment: I've managed to solve the issue. I've posted the working code above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the heads up about how to answer correctly.
I ended up creating a new function called check_row and used a select statement to check whether the row already exists. In this dataset, I only need to check whether a row in the table already contains value1(Symbol) and value2(Date) in order to keep the data accurate.
Thank you tutiplain for pointing me in this direction.

```
query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) from asx WHERE Symbol = %s AND Date = %s'
args = [value1, str_query_value2]
```

Here is the full code below.

```
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
import sys

ticker_file = 'C:/test.txt'

# Read the text file and add , to the end of the line.
def fun_read_file(ticker_file):
    #load_sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/test.txt' INTO TABLE asx FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';"
    host = 'localhost'
    user = 'user'
    password = 'password'
    db = 'trading'
    with open(ticker_file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            # Do something with 'line'
            stripped = line.strip('\n\r')
            value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7 = stripped.split(',')
            print(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7)
            # Call the check_row function
            check_row(host, user, password, db, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7)

# Insert row into table         
def csv_to_mysql(host, user, password, db, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7):
    '''
    This function load a csv file to MySQL table according to
    the load_sql statement.
    '''
    load_sql = 'INSERT INTO asx (Symbol,Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
    args = [value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7]
    try:
        con = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                                user=user,
                                password=password,
                                db=db,
                                autocommit=True,
                                local_infile=1)
        print('Connected to DB: {}'.format(host))
        # Create cursor and execute Load SQL
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(load_sql, args)
        print('Successfully loaded the table from csv.')
        con.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: {}'.format(str(e)))
        sys.exit(1)

# Check for duplicate row before insertion into table
def check_row(host, user, password, db, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7):
    # Manipulate the value2 (date) string first 20190111 into 2019-01-11
    str_value2 = value2
    year = str_value2[:4]
    day = str_value2[-2:]
    month = str_value2[4:6]
    str_query_value2 = year + '-' + month + '-' + day
    print(str_query_value2)
    # Select statement to query whether row already exists
    query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) from asx WHERE Symbol = %s AND Date = %s'
    args = [value1, str_query_value2]
    try:
        con = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                                user=user,
                                password=password,
                                db=db,
                                autocommit=True,
                                local_infile=1)
        print('Connected to DB: {}'.format(host))
        # Create cursor and execute Load SQL
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, args)
        print('Successfully queried the asx table.')
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
        # Fetchall method outputs a tuple. Access first item of the first tuple.
        int_result = result[0][0]
        print(int_result)
        con.close()

        if int_result >= 1:
            # Exit this function, 0 means clean exit, 1 means abort
            exit(0)
        else:
            # Call the csv_to_mysql function
            csv_to_mysql(host, user, password, db, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7)

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: {}'.format(str(e)))
        sys.exit(1)

# Execution the script
fun_read_file(ticker_file)
```